# When (Exactly) Does Bremsstrahlung Radiation Occur?

Tags: radiation

Regarding the Bremsstrahlung Radiation emitted when a charged particle curves inside a uniform magnetic field; Is there a way of calculating the angle through which the charged particle will precess before emitting the first quantum of radiation? Also, is there a way of determining the angle through which the charged particle will precess between the first and second emissions of radiation?

My investigations revealed only what I think are the angles of emission relative to the tangent of the curve [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bremsstrahlung#Angular_distribution).

Comment: There is surely no definite angle, only some probability distribution. I think that number of emitted photons (by a given time) is distributed according to Poisson, in each wavelength. You can (classically) compute the emitted spectrum, and convert it to averaged particles/second for each wavelength. Then use this and the form of the probability distribution to find the parameters of the distribution, so that you can e.g. compute the expectation values of this angles.

Comment: To emphasize what Peter has said, this is a *quantum mechanical* process. *Of course* it is ruled by probabilities.

Comment: Okay, so we all agree this is a probabilistic process. That doesn't invalidate the question. What are the expected values of these angles, as a function of field strength, particle mass, etc?

Comment: See Prof. Lewin's free MIT course, 8.03, specifically on accelerated charges. I have not seen a better video derivation of Larmor's formula, than by Lewin.

Answer (score 2):

Anytime a particle slows down or speeds up (non-relativistic).  The particle loses some energy as light.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larmor_formula

This could be in X-ray, UV, IR, Visible ect... This could be for any reason: particle-particle deflections, magnetic field and particle interactions, curved non uniform motion, electric field particle interactions, ect...

Bremsstrahlung is a really a subset of all radiation losses.  Including: synchrotron radiation, cyclotron radiation and visible radiation.  We define it as a certain set of conditions that lead to a chunk of spectrum radiating out. But this is antiqued thinking.  It is left over from when this radiation was first observed.

Really, Bremsstrahlung is just part of a much broader continuum of light radiation.  The underlining physical process is a change in the particles' speed. As the speed changes, energy leaves as light.